# How to only write the char = in a file without any end of line, in batch?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

How to create a single file with the = in it, and nothing else (If you open the file with XVI.exe, you will find only 3D (hexa) char. No CR or no LF char).

The usual way to echo without end of line is

```
set /p ==<nul
```

but it's not working with set, as the = is considered as a special char.

I've tried also with the carret but it's not working too.

```
set /p =^=<nul
set /p =^^=<nul
set /p =^^^=<nul
set /p =^^^^=<nul
```

Please remember before answering : only one char in the file, the =, there is the challenge !!!

Thanks,

ZeroDegres.

Comment: Good question, I'm stumped.  Is there a practical application for this question, or is it purely theoretical?  There are of course many easy solutions if you don't mind your batch file including some vbscript or powershell, but I assume you're wanting to stick with straight batch.

Comment: The more obvious solution was to write it directly in a file, but you've right, i just would have it into one script. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
call :createSub
> txt.tmp (echo(=!sub!)
copy txt.tmp /a txt.txt /b > nul
del txt.tmp
exit /b

:createSub
copy nul sub.tmp /a > nul
for /F %%a in (sub.tmp) DO (
   set "sub=%%a"
)
del sub.tmp
exit /b
```

`=` is in `txt.txt`.

([source](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=23564#p23564))

Comment: +1 LOL - I tried to figure out how you solve it, then I follow the link and saw that it's from myself

Comment: Excellent ! It's working. Thank you very much, with that, i will finish my binary writer today :)